# WP_Query for a taxonomy value OR a custom post type meta field

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, tax-query

I have a custom post type 'csl_playlist_manager', and one of its meta-fields is 'available_to_all'. I also have a custom hierarchical taxonomy, 'csl_source', which identifies the owner of each playlist. I need a query that allows me to find all suitable playlists for a particular source, where "suitable" means the playlist is either available_to_all OR a match for source or the children of source.

I've successfully created a list of ids for the source and its children, which deals with the taxonomy hierarchy issue. My query currently looks like this:

```
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'csl_playlist_manager',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'relation' => 'OR',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'csl_source',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $strTax,
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_csl_playlist_available_to_all',
            'value' => 1,
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
    'nopaging' => 'true',
);
```

var_dump reveals the resulting query is:

```
["request"]=>
  string(531) "SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (26,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44)
) AND ( 
  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_csl_playlist_available_to_all' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '1' )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'csl_playlist_manager' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC "
```

'AND' appears as the logical operator when I need it to be 'OR'.  I have searched widely but found no example of how to achieve the simple thing I'm trying to achieve.  Wisdom appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do — using the `OR` relation with the `tax_query` and `meta_query` parameters, i.e. to have a `<tax queries> OR <meta queries>` instead of `<tax queries> AND <meta queries>` command in SQL, unfortunately (without custom and *possibly complex* queries) is not possible in `WP_Query` for now, therefore that `'relation' => 'OR'` in your query args (the `$args` array) is not going to work or even do anything.

However, what you can (and I would) do, is: **Turn that metadata into a *custom taxonomy*** which is better suited for grouping a collection of posts together just like in your case where you used the metadata to group posts that are "playlist-available" (?), and moreover, taxonomy terms can also be as simple as `1` and `0`, and not necessarily need to be titles like `Movies` and `Web Design`. You could even create a custom metabox with a "Yes-or-No" checkbox which then updates the taxonomy terms for the post. (I mean, if you don't like the default taxonomy UI/selector..)

So for example, register a taxonomy named `playlist_available`, and then add these terms to that taxonomy: `1` ("Playlist available") and `0` ("Playlist not available") — although I think you may not need the latter..?

And then for all existing posts that had the metadata `_csl_playlist_available_to_all` set to `1`, remove that metadata from the post and then assign the post to the `1` term in the `playlist_available` taxonomy.

Then when you make your `WP_Query`, there's no need for the `meta_query` and just add another clause to the `tax_query` parameter/array:

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'csl_playlist_manager',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array( // selects posts that are in this taxonomy
            'taxonomy' => 'csl_source',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $strTax,
        ),
        array( // OR the ones with the playlist available
            'taxonomy' => 'playlist_available',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => '1', // or whatever the slug is
        ),
    ),
    // ... your other args.
);
```

And now that should give you the results you expected, and the query would also run faster than with the `meta_query` which could end up with various JOIN clauses — on small sites, you may not notice an obvious performance boost; but you would when your site gets larger (many posts, options, plugin data, traffic/users, etc.). <sup>But a bit of disclaimer, I'm far from being a performance expert. :)</sup>

Comment: Really!?  Is there really no way to specify OR between the elements of my search? I assumed it was just syntactic nuance I hadn't yet understood.

Comment: Unfortunately, none as far as I know for the time being - and that top-level `'relation' => 'OR'` you've attempted won't work because that `relation` isn't part of the main parameters.

Comment: Remember, you're trying to use the `OR` relation between the `tax_query` and `meta_query` - and not between clauses **inside** those parameters, and that is not supported by default, so your option for now would be using a hook like in my example. But of course, the other (better) option would be to turn that metadata into a custom taxonomy or just use an existing taxonomy.

Comment: Your final remark - better to turn it into a  custom taxonomy - I read that advice elsewhere and considered it, but the field is just a boolean 1 or 0. That doesn't seem to fit the taxonomy concept, but do I misunderstand?

Comment: A taxonomy is to group a collection into one, so whether the term's value is a boolean or string, a simple 1 or 0 number, or a category name like 'Movies', 'Web Design', etc. they'd eventually still form a collection - and for example in your case, you're using the metadata to mark posts that are "available" and not, so you could create a taxonomy `playlist_available` with just two terms `1` and `0`, then use them in your `tax_query` and you'd notice the query runs faster than with the meta query - which could end up with various JOIN clauses.

Comment: I was not clever enough to get it working, though I don't doubt your solution for a moment. However I created the extra taxonomy and have it working that way. I greatly appreciate your help, but unfortunately can't provide evidence for your result.

Comment: In that case, then do you think you can accept the revised answer? :)

Comment: Definitely, and thanks for all your excellent help. I'm climbing a steep curve in using Wordpress properly.  Better use of taxonomies is on the menu, and this has definitely helped.